# OpenLayers 6 - reprojected GeoJSON data not displaying on map

Tags: openlayers, proj4js

I'm using latest OpenLayers (6.1.1) and proj4js 2.6.0 to display a multipoint geometry.

I first define my input data project with proj4 then create an open layer vector source as follow:

```js
proj4.defs("EPSG:2154","+proj=lcc +lat_1=49 +lat_2=44 +lat_0=46.5 +lon_0=3 +x_0=700000 +y_0=6600000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs")
ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4)

var profile = '{ "type": "Feature", "geometry" : { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ 308007.223185, 6652665.6637, -0.167366668582 ], [ 308008.22140099998796, 6652665.6039899997413, -0.131412133574 ] ] } }'

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(profile, {
        dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
        featureProjection: 'EPSG:2154',
    }),
});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM(),
      name: 'source-osm',
      visible: true,
      opacity: 0.7,
    }),
    vectorLayer,
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-1.95, 47.2]),
    zoom: 10,
  })
});
```

Problem is the data doesn't appear on map. If I have a look at the vector source object in the console, it tells me that `projection_: null`.

If I do not specify a reprojection, points are displayed (but at an incorrect position obviously).

I checked using [epsg.io](https://epsg.io/) that my points coordinates are correct.

Any idea?

Comment: Why are you setting feature projection to EPSG:2154 when your view is EPSG:3854?  If you zoom out you may find them somewhere on the map but not where you expect.

Comment: Your data projection is not EPSG:4326.  If the coordinates in your GeoJSON are EPSG:2154 and your view is EPSG:3854 you need `dataProjection: 'EPSG:2154', featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'`

Comment: You're right, I mixed things up between EPSG:4326 and EPSG:3857 ! This is still quite new to me so I may revised those EPSG codes :) . Also, I got confused by the difference between `dataProjection` and `featureProjection` in the documentation, I got wrong indeed, thx !

Comment: FYI, for GeoJSON, you should never use `EPSG:2154` for your data coordinates. Default is WGS 84 (`EPSG:4326`) an other CRS are not recommended in the GeoJSON specification although you can use them.

Comment: @ThomasG77 OK, this is interesting. I guess I should make the transformation before serializing my geometry into GeoJSON then.